# Compact sets are bounded

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to prove that a compact subset, $K$, of a metric space $(X,d)$ is bounded, ***using the sequential definition of compactness***. So far I have the following, but am unsure about where to go next. Am I at least on the right track?

I decided to proceed by contradiction, assuming that $K$ is unbounded (and arriving at a contradiction of the fact that $K$ is compact). I first tried to construct a sequence in $K$, using the fact of $K$'s unboundedness, which I conjectured would not have a convergent subsequence. I constructed it as follows.

If $K$ is unbounded, then, for any $M>0$, there exists $x,y\in K$ s.t. $d(x,y)>M$. As such, we may construct the following sequence, in $K$. Let $a_{1}, a_{2}$ be chosen s.t. $d(a_{1}, a_{2})>1$. Generally, for each $n \in \{1,3,5,...\}$, let $a_{n}, a_{n+1}$ be chosen such that $d(a_{n}, a_{n+1})>n$. This completes the construction of $\{a_{n}\}$, which we now prove does not satisfy the Cauchy Criterion.

Consider some arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, and $N \in\mathbb{N}$. Choose $j\in \{1, 3, 5,...\}$ such that $j>\max\{N, \epsilon\}$. Then, set $n=j, m=j+1$. We have that $d(a_{n}, a_{m})=n>\epsilon$, where $m,n>N$. Hence, $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not Cauchy.

At this point, realising that a non-Cauchy sequence can yet have a convergent subsequence, I became stuck. I wonder whether my stronger result implies that the sequence I constructed cannot have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Don't argue by contradiction. Fix a point $x$, and note that the open sets $B(x,n)=\{y\mid d(x,y)\lt n\}$, $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ form an open cover for $K$. Then use compactness.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am asked to prove this using a sequential definition of compactness

Comment: Can you point me to the part of your post that says this? Are readers supposed to know this, or just guess? If you want to be given useful help, then perhaps you should give the required information in the post.

Comment: HINT: Show that if a set $X$ is unbounded, and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in X$, then there exists $x_{n+1}\in X$ such that $d(x_i,x_{n+1})\gt 1$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Also, note that when you negate a statement, you have to exchange the quantifiers $\forall \leftrightarrow \exists$, so the negation of the Cauchy convergence condition reads "*There exists* $\varepsilon > 0$ such that *for all* $N > 0$ *there exist* indices $m, n \geq N$ such that $d(x_m, x_n) \geq \varepsilon$." Importantly, you get to choose any $\varepsilon$ that allows you to always find points at least that far apart from one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to inform you that the method u've presented so far needs some modification to continue.
The problem comes from the way you construct a sequence divergent to infinity.To show that why this type of construction could give us a sequence that has convergent subsequence, we assume that$(X,d)=\mathbb{R}$ and K unbounded but compact. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence defined as follows :
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},x_{2n}=2n,x_{2n-1}=0$$
It is clear that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, d(x_{n+1},x_n)=|x_{n+1}-x_n|=2n>n$. However it has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{2n-1}\}$.

So why such construction does not work well? In fact, if you choose "arbitrarily" a point to be $a_{n+1}$ such that $d(a_n,a_{n+1})>n$, then you have the risk that $a_{n+1}$ lives close to some point before ($a_1,a_3,a_{3k-1}$, e.t.c).Therefore, if you want to continue this method (that is, to construct a sequence divergent to infinity),you should specify the way you choose $\{a_n\}$'s to avoid the case mentioned above.